# How to copy the value of a drop down listbox to all listboxes in the same table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having an issue, I would like to copy the value of the last drop down listbox filled, to the rest of listboxes defined.

Here is the code I have :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("table input[name='copy']").click(function() {
      $(this).parents("tr").children("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(element).children().length != 0) {
          $(element).nextAll(":not(:last-child)").html($(element).children().clone())
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th width="10%">id</th>
      <th width="10%">fn</th>
      <th width="10%">ln</th>
      <th width="10%">usr</th>
      <th width="10%">type</th>
      <th width="10%">1</th>
      <th width="10%">2</th>
      <th width="10%">3</th>
      <th width="10%">4</th>
      <th width="10%">5</th>
      <th width="10%">Copy</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>TE</td>
      <td>TE</td>
      <td>userTe</td>
      <td>fulltime</td>
      <td>
        <select class="t1">
          <option>CP</option>
          <option value="2">RC</option>
          <option value="3">CP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="t1">
          <option>CP</option>
          <option value="2">RC</option>
          <option value="3">CP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="t1">
          <option>CP</option>
          <option value="2">RC</option>
          <option value="3">CP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="t4">
          <option></option>
          <option value="2">RC</option>
          <option value="3">CP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="t5">
          <option></option>
          <option value="2">RC</option>
          <option value="3">CP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input name="copy" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the following fiddle which works well, but it does not work on my computer... 
[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxba7fjn/1/)

Can someone tells me what to do to fix it ? thanks in advance

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say 'the last dropdown box filled' do you mean the last one in the row, or the last one the user interacted with?

Comment: Also note that your jQuery logic needs a document.ready event handler, as you're running it in the `head`

Comment: Hi Rory,
the last one in the row.